# Absolute Position Vertical Nav with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make a vertical nav that say will be 50px and then I want to have a flex area that has my header, main content area and footer.

Right now when I use absolute the flexbox container gets covered over as absolute it doing it's own thing. I am wondering if I can tell my flex container to start 50px from the left so I don't have to worry about icons and such getting swallowed up by it.

Do I have to make the flex container absolute as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `margin-left:50px` on the flex area to make it start at `50px;`

see code sample

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav"></div>
  <div class="flex-container">text sample</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any *positioning* or *margins*, just make it natural with the additional `flex` *wrapper*:

```css
body {margin: 0}

.outerFlex {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  height: 100vh; /* 100% of the viewport height */
}

nav {
  flex-basis: 50px; /* initial width */
  background: lightblue;
}

.innerFlex {
  flex: 1; /* takes the remaining width */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* stacks flex-items vertically */
  background: lightgreen;
}

main {
  flex: 1; /* takes the remaining height */
}
```

```html
<div class="outerFlex">
  <nav>Nav</nav>
  <div class="innerFlex">
    <header>Header</header>
    <main>Main</main>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to have the nav slide in and out, it is possible with what you have of course but with absolute/relative it over top and main area won't shrink

Comment: I see, well yes, then that's a different case.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to position your nav as absolute or fixed, then give padding/margin that equals the width of your nav to the main content.
Here's an example.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.left-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 50px;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.1);
}
.main-header {
  background: red;

}
.main-body {
  background: green;
}
.main-footer {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-nav">Nav</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="main-header">Header</div>
    <div class="main-body">Body</div>
    <div class="main-footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```